# Building a CLI tool with gluegun throws command not found

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a CLI with gluegun and I'm encountering an error while following the base tutorial. Here are the steps I'm following:

```bash
# spin up your new CLI
npx gluegun new movies

# choose TypeScript or Modern JavaScript
# now jump into the source
cd movies

# and link your new executable
yarn link

# and run it!
movies help
```

After running `movies help`, I get the error message `zsh: command not found: movies`.

Comment: yarn v1.22.1; node: v16.20.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct PATH set in your `~/.zshrc` file.

After adding this line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"
```

Everything worked fine for me.

Check out the docs: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable

Comment: Expand "Alternatives" -> Scroll down until you see "Path Setup"

Comment: `yarn` was set in my `PATH` just fine, I was able to run `yarn test` and other `yarn` commands in general. But running the command you shared from inside the gluegun project folder made it work, could you help me understand why?